# Send email through proxy

Tags: laravel, email, proxy, laravel-mail

I am trying to send an email to a guest in laravel.
Below is my code:

```
Mail::to($requestor->email)->send(new ApprovedNotification(auth()->user()->name));
```

The question is how can I send the email through proxy? Does it requires any server side configuration or I can just set it in laravel? The code is running fine when I am using my home network but when using my company server, the SMTP can't be sent out. ( The weird thing is the Jetstream team invitation email can be sent, but the customized emails cant)

Below is my email configuration ( I am using App password generated from google account) :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

This is the error I get:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.googlemail.com:587 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try other `MAIL_PORT` number as `2525` or `465`.

Comment: Test this, change `MAIL_DRIVER` to sendmail. Don't forget after each change do `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but still getting the same error:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.googlemail.com:2525 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) @ParisaN